# Актуальный курс валют с помощью Ангуляр

Tags: angularjs, angular

Помогите, пожалуйста, начала изучать Ангуляр и очень сложно идет пока. Я хочу сделать конвертер валют и также отображать актуальный курс валют (доллар и евро) по отношению к гривне , сам конвертер я сделала, а вот с курсом валют ломаю голову.

```
<div>
  <p > 1 USD <span>=</span> {{}}</p>
  <p>1 EUR <span>=</span> {{}}</p>
</div>
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="selection-container">
    <input #c3  min="1" type="text" (mouseleave)="amounts(c3.value)" required>
    <select #c1 name="" id="country1" (mouseleave)="changebase(c1.value)">
      <option value="USD">US dollar</option>
      <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
      <option value="UAH">Ukranian Grivna</option>
    </select>
    <p>  to </p>

    <select #c2  name="" id="country1" (mouseleave)="tocountry(c2.value)">
      <option value="USD">US dollar</option>
      <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
      <option value="UAH">Ukranian Grivna</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button (click)="convert()"> Submit</button>
  <div class="result-container">
    <p>{{base}} <span>=</span>{{result}} {{cont2}}</p>


  </div>
</div>
```

В первом диве я хочу отоброжать актуальный курс валют

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http"

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CurrencydataService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  getcurrencydata(country1:string){
    let url ="https://api.exchangerate.host/latest?base=USD"+country1
    return this.http.get(url)
  }
}
```

мой запрос на сервер

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CurrencydataService } from './currencydata.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-app';
  currjson:any =[];

curencyuds = "USD";
currencyeur ="EUR"

  base ="USD";
  cont2="USD";
  result:any = [];
  amount:any = [];
  


  changebase(a:string){
    this.base =a;
    console.log(this.base)
  }
  tocountry(b:string){
    this.cont2 = b;
    console.log(this.cont2)

  }

  amounts(c:string){
    this.amount = c;
    console.log(this.amount)

  }

  

  constructor(private currency:CurrencydataService){}
  convert(){


    console.log(this.base)
    console.log(this.cont2)
    console.log(this.amount)



    this.currency.getcurrencydata(this.base).subscribe(data=>{
      this.currjson= JSON.stringify(data);
      this.currjson= JSON.parse(this.currjson);
      this.amount = JSON.parse(this.amount)
     // this.current =JSON.parse(this.currjson.rates.UAH)


     console.log(this.result)
     console.log(this.currjson.rates)
     console.log(this.currjson)




      if (this.cont2 ==="USD"){
        this.result = this.currjson.rates.USD * (this.amount)

      }


      if (this.cont2 ==="EUR"){
        this.result = this.currjson.rates.EUR * (this.amount)
      }


      if (this.cont2 ==="UAH"){
        this.result = this.currjson.rates.UAH * (this.amount)
      }
    })

  }
}
```

Логика моего конвертера
Подскажите,пожалуйста, как правильно вытянуть данные и получить актуальный курс гривны по отношению к евро и доллару

Comment: Не могли бы поделится исходным кодом?

Answer (score 1):

Зачем Вам это?

`this.currjson= JSON.stringify(data);`

data - это объект

Просто работайте с ним

да и в

`url ="https://api.exchangerate.host/latest?base=USD"+country1`

+country1 лишнее

Просто забирайте всю портянку по USD, а уже из data.rates забирайте нужную Вам валюту по отношению к USD

data.rates.UAH - даст количество гривен на доллар
аналогично запускаете для EUR.

или еще лучше, используйте

`url ="https://api.exchangerate.host/latest?base=UAH"`

если Вам нужны исключительно курсы гривны.

Само собой, Вы получите курс UAH/USD, для USD/UAH нужно использовать обратную дробь 1/х .

Не забывайте про обработку ошибок и исключений.